# Condition if there exists any event at specific day

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I just modified some functions such as extended drag and modify them to save a timestamp (start and end) into a hidden input (I send those information to MySQL). But one of the conditions is that event that I dragged can't exist with another event in one day. Is there any method in fullcallendar that can tell me if that condition is fulfilled?

Thanks for answers. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could implement the [eventDrop](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_ui/eventDrop/) function so that it calls [clientEvents](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/clientEvents/) to see if there are any events that overlap the one that has been dropped.